# How can I change the default output number form to accounting form?

Tags: number-representation

By default, large numbers are displayed in scientific form in output like `1.2345 x 10^8` in *Mathematica* 8.0.4, but I would prefer having numbers in accounting form like `123,450,000` in output.

How can I change the default output number form from scientific form to accounting form?

Comment: What happens when you enter "number format" into the search form of the Documentation Center?

Comment: Of course I tried the documentation center for days. But it led me nowhere, so I decided to ask here.

Comment: Showing what you tried encourages people to help you.  It also lets them see what you are doing wrong.  The first three or four links in this [google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=tutorial+format+number+mathematica&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) yield pages that probably contain the answer to your question, especially the second two.

Answer (score 3):

Under **Edit** > **Preferences** > **Appearance** > **Numbers** there is a **Formatting** tab.

Or you could do something like:

```
$PrePrint = AccountingForm;
```

Comment: oho - the famous Fing-Longer!

Comment: @Yves A man can dream...

Comment: Does that mean you are friends with the (ex-) toad now?

Comment: @Yves We're always friendly, unless [he tries to kill me](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8219857#8219857). ;-)

Comment: That´s what I´d term a *robust* relationship, then.

Comment: @YvesKlett Who's an ex-toad?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Wizard for your help. Although the Preference tap did not the work that I needed, $PrePrint does work!

Comment: @user6139 I'm glad it helps.  If you need more specific output look at `NumberForm` and its full set of options.  By the way I didn't downvote this question and I'm not certain why it got the response it did but I think if you had shown or even described your efforts people might have been kinder.