# Avoid unnecessary truncation

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, number-representation

Is there any way to change the general settings in Mathematica so that when I type e.g.

```
0.34*60000000
```

I get the output

```
20400000.
```

as opposed to the (for me not useful) representation

```
2.04*10^7
```

?

i.e. I want the raw number, not the formatted/adjusted form. And I do not want to use operators like SetPrecision. Ideally, I just want to change the settings so that whenever I type in a number I get the full answer. Is this possible? Perhaps using some command like SetOptions[$FrontEnd, ... ?

Comment: You can use `0.34*60000000 // AccountingForm` I do not know now to set this to be automatically applied to each number printed. see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20373/how-can-i-change-the-default-output-number-form-to-accounting-form (I think the answer you want is there, just saw it)

Comment: It seems when I use $PrePrint = AccountingForm I get exactly what I want. Thanks! But is there a way to keep the digit block seperator set to "Thin Space"?

Comment: I think you can using MakeBoxes, but I am not good at that. AccountingForm allready supports setting of DigitsBlocks. Try this: `AccountingForm[0.34*60000000, DigitBlock -> 3,  
 NumberSeparator -> ","]` But I do not know how to tell it to use small space for separator. Using `NumberSeparator -> " "` will make the space too large.

Comment: Is there a way to modify $PrePrint = AccountingForm using NumberSeparator in order to make it generally applicable? As I said, I do not want to type in AccountingForm every time.

Comment: I think it will be good idea to close this question, since it has an answer already, and post a new question specific to "How to make $PrePrint use AccountingForm with small space for Block separator". This way it will be more specific question, or rename the question, edit as needed.

Comment: You use use the same $PrePrint command, like this: `$PrePrint = AccountingForm[#, DigitBlock -> 3, NumberSeparator -> " "] &;`  I just do not know how to make the separator small.

Comment: for the sake of completion: replacing the " " by "\[ThinSpace]" gives the thin space.

Comment: Just to note, one needs "\"  added before [] in the above. But this forum does not show it. So for OP, make sure to add the escape "\" like this:  "*****HERE****[ThinSpace]"

Comment: @Nasser I would recommend posting an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `$PrePrint`

```
  $PrePrint = AccountingForm[#, DigitBlock -> 3, NumberSeparator -> "\[ThinSpace]"] &;
```

You can the above to your [init.m](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/file/init.m.html), so it is loaded each time you start Mathematica and do not have to write it each time.

More information on [`AccountingForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AccountingForm.html)

Thanks to hint by Tom on the ThinSpace syntax. Related [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20373/how-can-i-change-the-default-output-number-form-to-accounting-form) by MrWizard.